# Insert , schedule update in mongodb in an express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing an application in which I have to fetch data from a 3rd party API.I want to store this data in my mongodb database and schedule a job after every 5hrs, which again fetches data from the same 3rd party API and update my db (I want to do this because the data from the 3rd party API contains fields which expire after a certain period and I want to customize its usage).

I'm uncertain of how to do this.Should I use `node-cron` library to accomplish this? Or use some other way? Is my approach correct?
If I use this approach,will inserting many documents and updating them be possible using `mongoose` ?

Comment: setInterval(update,5*24*60*60*1000)

Comment: @Jonasw : So no need to use `node-cron`for my use case? and does `mongoose` support updating many?

Comment: using `node-cron` is perfectly fine. And yes updating multiple documents is supported by mongoose.

Comment: @RahulSharma : How will I update the whole collection?